# Import Page with Web Part

Tags: web-part, publishing-page, import

Why when I import a publishing page with web part in the page content, the web part is declared "closed" and goes into closed web parts?

Answer (score 0):

When you import a Web Part in the Page Content, it is not assigned to any particular Web Part Zone, and thus it shows in the Closed Web Parts category.
The reference to the Web Part is embedded into the HTML for the Page Content (or Content Editor Web Part).

Comment: I note it, but, try this:
1. Import on page with a web part in page content
2. Edit the page and put the closed(s) web parts in any place of the page content.
3. DON'T SAVE the page. CANCEL EDIT.
4. DISCARD the check-in.
5. Reload the page

To me, the web parts back on display usually. This is strange because it seems he knew associated content, only there was no such link-level database or something